# How to connect dual 5-pin GS232 to a single 8-pin G-5500 Rotator

Tags: cables, interface, cable-assemblies

I have a Yaesu GS232 computer interface which has two 5-pin slots, one for elevation and one for azimuth. This is supposed to be connected to a Yaesu G5500 Rotator which has a 8 pin DIN slot. Supplied with the G5500 was one 5-pin --> MinDIN which controls azimuth.
It's not clear to me why a secondary cable to control elevation is not supplied as standard with this rotator.
Images of the connectors and the pin outs are shown below:
[image]
[image]

I am not entirely sure how I would go about making a cable that would connect these two parts and there is not one readily available to buy, please correct me if I am mistaken, does anyone have any ideas on how to go from the 2 x 5-pins to a single 8-pin, so does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Connect them together, or replace one? The manufacturer should be able to sell you a cable. (Did someone delete my comment? I believe I asked this earlier)

Comment: @gbulmer I am not looking to replace the GS232, just looking to manufacture a cable that would make the link between the two which would involve changing two 5-pins to one 8-pin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem! It's most odd that the cable isn't supplied as standard. I've built my own and it works perfectly. I've also written a [blog post](http://speakingwithspace.wordpress.com/2014/11/21/building-your-own-dual-5-pin-to-din-cable-to-connect-the-yaesu-gs232-to-the-yaesu-g-5500/) on how to do it.

I hope this helps!

Comment: It's worth adding some more details here about the cable, link-only answers are discouraged because they can become useless in the future if the link dies.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to talk to the G-5500, and replace the GS232 with something else?

You could make a 'break out' cable for the 8pin G-5500 socket. Wire it to an 8pin 0.1" header so that nothing touches accidentally, and it is easy to do some experiments on a breadboard.

Pins 2, 4, are azimuth, and so correspond to 1 and 2 on the 5-pin socket socket/plug.
Pins 3 and 5 are elevation, and correspond to 1 and 2 on the 5-pin elevation socket/plug.

I don't understand pin 1 of the 8-pin socket at all. The others don't seem necessary for now, except ground (assuming the controller has its own power supply)

Give it a try.